# npm doesn't install dependencies of packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I have the next content inside my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.24.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bowser": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "commander": "^2.19.0",
    "esdoc": "^1.1.0",
    "esdoc-standard-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "terser": "^3.14.1",
    "velocity-animate": "^1.5.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.8",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.8",
    "vuex": "^3.1.0",
    "webfonts-generator": "^0.4.0"
}
```

I'm trying to install packages using `npm i`. After that I'm getting the same named directories inside `node_modules` but without any sub-dependencies of these packages.

For example `@symfony/webpack-encore` depends on `webpack`. But it is not installed. Package-lock was created with full tree that contains `webpack`.

Removing of `node_modules` or `package-lock.json` doesn't help.

---

But if I delete `node_modules` and do `npm update` (not `npm install`), then it installed successfully but without any changes inside `package-lock.json` and `package.json` (according to git diff)

## Update

If I delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then `npm i` works good.

Comment: *Package-lock was created with full tree that contains webpack* - how? The said package.json will result in installing all nested dependencies including webpack and `npm i --package-lock-only` will generate a correct package lock. Whatever the problem is, it's specific to your package-lock.json which wasn't shown and likely became corrupted under unknown circumstances.